# Boto3 Video Upload 0 Bytes from Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, amazon-s3, ffmpeg, boto3

I have a small Flask api that takes a video and an image, overlays the image on the video and uploads the result to Amazon S3. I am using ffmpeg to do the actual overlaying. Here is that code:

```
command = "ffmpeg -i {0} -i {1} -filter_complex \"overlay=0:0\" {2}".format(background_name, overlay_name, output_name)
subprocess.getoutput(command)
```

Then I simply upload it via Boto3:

```
s3.upload_file(output_name, VIDEO_BUCKET_NAME, output_name)
```

This code works fine when I run on localhost; however, when I test in while deployed to Heroku, it always uploads a file with 0 bytes. I suspect that it may be a problem with Heroku's transient filesystem, but the file is being used immediately after it is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this doesn't really answer my question, but I took the API off of Heroku and deployed it on AWS Elastic Beanstalk and now both image and video uploads work correctly.